# Purpose of "rows" when adding Long Text field

Tags: entities

When adding a Long Text field to a content type, I am asked to supply the number of *rows* for the field. What is the purpose of this?

[image: Screenshot of Rows field]

This seems like it has something to do with how the data is stored in the database. At first I thought it was required because I was using a SQLite database that stores everything in a flat file, so I switched to a MySQL backend. However, the field is still required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rows control the height of your text area for editors. It does not change how the data is stored in the database.

Comment: It maps directly onto a textarea HTML tag attribute, for example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0):

Number of row will be display to end user at a time.